# Having the heading of my table 1 character wide >> rotating text (or something else?)

Tags: css

I would like to have my heading texts vertical and not horizontal to keep my columns only 1 character wide. Possible?

[image]

By 'vertical', I mean:

S

A

M

P

L

E

Or rotating the text by 90°

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard mechanism in css for rotating the text :

```
.rotate {

/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

}
```

But that doesn't work so good on all browsers : sometimes the width is computed before the rotation, leading to strange effects. You have to test to see if it's good for your problem.

EDIT : the new, more complete, solution was stolen from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/ (IE was missing before, as was pointed by JonathanSampson)

Comment: Don't forget [`-ms-transform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff974936.aspx).

Comment: Maybe, I have'nt tested on IE recently. I suggest Bronzato add -ms-transform and test on all browsers.

Comment: @JonathanSampson What do you mean by don't forget -ms-transform?

Comment: @Bronzato The CSS rules above used 3 of the four major prefixed forms. `-ms-` wasn't included, and as such the effect wouldn't have been seen in IE browsers supporting this feature.

Comment: Added a link with a complete reference (all browsers).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this -

- The clean way: Add `<br>` (line break) after each character
- The CSS way: Use `width: 1em` to indicate that you want the width of the character `m` in the font. For a fixed width font, this will work as you expect it to. But it might not always work with a variable width font (which is the one you'll be likely using)

User actions like overriding style sheets, zooming, re-ordering of content can mess with your styles. The first method is safe from these issues

Comment: With your solution (width: 1em) the characters are not wrapped on the next line. Any idea?

Comment: It seems a space is required between the characters http://jsfiddle.net/eTTL5/ I'll update the answer if I figure out how to do this without spaces